# Cambiar el valor de una variable global dentro de una funcion

Tags: javascript, funciones, variables, variables-globales

se que tal vez es un problema muy tonto, pero como seteo una variable global dentro de una funcion?

algo asi:

```
const objeto={}

objeto.preregistrarUsuario=(req,res)=>
{
      let variableGlobal=false;

  db.query(`SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE correo=?`,correo, (err, rows, fields) => 
    {
        if(!err) 
        {
            if(rows.length>0)
            {
                variableGlobal=true; //SETEARLA AQUI
            }
            else
            {
                variableGlobal=false; //SETEARLA AQUI
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
}

console.log(variableGlobal); --> que aqui me aparezca true cuando se cambie el valor
```

Comment: Tal vez te sirva esta [información](https://uniwebsidad.com/libros/javascript/capitulo-4/ambito-de-las-variables).

Comment: Gracias, la verdad ya lo habia visto, pero me quede igual :/

Answer (score 3):

Un pequeño ejemplo, espero lo entiendas, cualquier duda hazla saber. :) Puedes ver más informacion acerca de [let y var](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/let)

```js
var txt = "No digo nada"; //declaro esta variable de forma global, se utiliza var y no let

function nombre(x){ //Creo una función y le paso un parámetro

  if(x.length > 5){//en este caso es una cadena, y valido si es mayor a 5
    
    txt = 'El nombre tiene más de 5 letras'; // Le asigno un nuevo mensaje en caso de que se cumpla esta condición
  
  }else{
  
    txt = 'El nombre tiene menos de 5 letras'; //En caso de que no le asigno este mensaje
  }

}

console.log(txt); //Mando un console log, para que mires como imprimi mi variable global
nombre('Rogelio');//Pasamos un nombre
console.log(txt);//Después de que se ejecuta la función el valor de txt cambia dependiendo la condición, en este caso te dirá que el nombre tiene más de 5 letras

nombre('Alan');//Una vez más llamas la función y le pasas otro parámetro ahora un nombre con 4 letras
console.log(txt);//ahora el valor de txt es un mensaje que dice que el nombre tiene menos de 5 letras.
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, al final implemente otra manera para solucionar un problema que tenia relacionado con este tema, decidi no usar variables globales, estoy desarrollando un proyecto y estoy seguro que me surgira la necesidad de venir a este pos nuevamentet, le daré una repasada a let y var, porque pense que let solo era la nueva forma de declarar variables en Js y leyendo el link que me mandaste me doy cuenta que no es asi, nuevamente gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: No hay de que Alexyz, yo siempre utilizo `var` y en este tema de la variables globales lo entendí practicando, para pasar valores de función a función, no domino javascript ni mucho menos, pero investigando y practicando amplias el conocimiento. :D

Answer (score 2):

En esta línea está el conflicto:

```
objeto.preregistrarUsuario=(req,res)=>
{
      let variableGlobal=false; // AQUÍ ESTA.

  db.query(`SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE correo=?`,correo, (err, rows, fields) =>
```

Al momento de declarar la variable con `let` estas diciendo que la variable será local, o sea, que será utilizada sólo dentro del bloque en el que la declaras **(NO SERÁ UTILIZADA EN UN BLOQUE ANIDADO O FUERA DEL BLOQUE DE DECLARACIÓN)**.
Para declarar una variable global deberías usar `var` en vez de `let`.
Así quedaría el código:

```
const objeto={}

objeto.preregistrarUsuario=(req,res)=>
{
      var variableGlobal=false; // SE CAMBIA 'let' POR 'var'

  db.query(`SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE correo=?`,correo, (err, rows, fields) => 
    {
        if(!err) 
        {
            if(rows.length>0)
            {
                variableGlobal=true;
            }
            else
            {
                variableGlobal=false;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
}

console.log(variableGlobal);
```

Comment: `Para declarar una variable global deberías usar var en vez de let`. Eso es nuevo. Hasta donde yo se, `let` se usa para otra cosa :-O

Comment: Gracias, investigaré mas acerca de var y let porque al parecer si es let te restringe el scope.

Comment: De nada. Suerte con tu proyecto :D

Answer (score 1):

No dices si estás en el navegador o en `node.js`. En ambos casos, la idea es la misma, solo cambia un pequeño detalle.

En Javascript, todas las variables *globales* son, en realidad, **miembros de un único objeto**: en el navegador, `window`. En `node.js`, el objeto se llama ... `global`.

En el navegador:

```
if( rows.length > 0) {
  window.variableGlobal = true; //SETEARLA AQUI
} else {
  window.variableGlobal = false; //SETEARLA AQUI
}
```

En `node.js`:

```
if( rows.length > 0) {
  global.variableGlobal = true; //SETEARLA AQUI
} else {
  global.variableGlobal = false; //SETEARLA AQUI
}
```